# How to use Vue Router in Vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm learning Vue, and started of with [the webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/tree/master/template/src). The first thing I'm trying to do is to add support for Vue Router, but I've spent several hours on it now without being able to render a single route (I always end up with a blank page). Frustrating!

I simply want to have a single `.vue` file, acting as the layout file, into which different `.vue` files, acting as "pages", are rendered into. Can someone tell me how to do this, please? Here's my latest failed attempt:

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App'
import Home from './components/Home'
import About from './components/About'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    { path: '/about', component: About }
]

const app = new Vue({
    router: new VueRouter({
        routes
    }),
    component: App
}).$mount('#app')
```

App.vue (the layout file)

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>Hello App!</h1>
        <p>
            <router-link to="/">Go to Foo</router-link>
            <router-link to="/about">Go to Bar</router-link>
        </p>

        <router-view></router-view>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    }

</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

components/About.vue (almost identical to components/Home.vue)

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>About</h1>
        <p>This is the about page!</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: Please try to create webpackbin for that. It is really strange that it is not working so you probably have some little error in code somewhere...

Comment: Sorry @MU, I just realized an error in the code I had (there has been a lot of try-and-errors lately, so now I'm not sure how anything works anymore ^^'), but the code I posted was wrong. I've now updated it (changed the main.js file), can you take a look at it again, please?

Comment: Also, when I inspect the page in Chrome, I see `<div id="app"></div>`, so my `App` component has not been rendered at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally got it to work. The main.js file should be written like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App'
import Home from './pages/Home'
import About from './pages/About'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    { path: '/about', component: About }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes
})

const app = new Vue({
    router,
    template: '<App />',
    components: {
        App
    }
}).$mount('#app')
```

I hope this saves hours of trouble for someone else.

**EDIT**

The following:

```
const app = new Vue({
    router,
    template: '<App />',
    components: {
        App
    }
}).$mount('#app')
```

can preferably be replaced with:

```
const app = new Vue({
    router,
    render: function(createElement){
        return createElement(App)
    }
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Regarding your edit, the difference is that the `template` option is for the stand-alone version of Vue, whereas you need the `render` option if using the runtime-only version.

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to get `main.js` to call the `index.js` file in folder `router` and work with the routes defined there:

I had created my app via the VUE UI (with VUE 3.1 and CLI/3)

In the VUE UI there is an option to add plugins. I chose the router plugin (route)  and it asked if I want to install a new route or install the framework. (You first need to install the framework...)

It then changed my main.js file to have the following: (the additions are marked with comments)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import './plugins/axios'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router' // added by router plugin

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router, // added by router plugin
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

It also added a new folder `router` and in it `index.js` with the code

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
// import Hello from '@/components/HelloWorld' // @pashute: I added this later...

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
    // { 
    //    path: '/',
    //    name: 'Hello',
    //    component: Hello
    // }
]

// eslint-disable-next-line no-new
const router = new VueRouter({
   routes
})

export default router
```

It also installed the latest router package and added a link in the HelloWorld component to the router documentation.

By the way, notice the extra `name:` in the route definitions.